# Ember 3+ passing action from component to controller not working

Tags: ember.js, controller, components, closures

We have recently shifted from ember 2+ to Ember 3.18.0 and i am struggling to call the controller function from a component. In previous version we were using sendAction to bubble the action but now as sendAction is depreciated and closures are being used i am not able to make it correctly.

Below is my code

Controller.hbs

```
{{generic-err-modal err=receivedErr showDialog= this.showErrorModal onSave=(action "closePromptDialog")}}
```

Controller.js

```
@action
closePromptDialog(){
    this.set("showErrorModal",false);
}
```

Component.hbs

```
    {{#if @showDialog}}
  <PaperDialog id="genericModal" class="flex-50" @fullscreen={{fullscreen}} @onClose={{action "closePromptDialog"}} @origin={{dialogOrigin}}>
      <PaperDialogContent class="text-align-center">
          {{paper-icon "remove_circle_outline" class="red" size=48}}
      </PaperDialogContent>
      <PaperDialogContent>
        <h2>{{@err.errorMessage}}</h2>
      </PaperDialogContent>

      <PaperDialogActions @class="layout-row">
        <span class="flex"></span>
        <PaperButton @primary={{true}} @onClick={{action "hideModal"}} @raised={{true}}>Ok</PaperButton>
      </PaperDialogActions>

  </PaperDialog>
{{/if}}
```

Component.js

```
@action
hideModal(){
    this.args.onSave();
}
```

on this i am getting error as

```
Uncaught TypeError: method is not a function
```

Any help will be very much appreciated.

Ember version i am using is 3.18.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From Octane edition, everything becomes more explicit in Ember  One such thing is the `{{action}}` helper to pass functions. In classic (pre-octane) model, when passing a string to the `action` helper like, `{{action "closePromptDialog"}}`, Ember will search for the action `closePromptDialog` inside the `actions` hash of the corresponding controller as mentioned in the [example in the guide.](https://guides.emberjs.com/v3.10.0/templates/actions/)

Since the introduction of native class and `@action` decorator, we don't have to use the `{{action}}` helper as well as `actions` hash. We can directly pass the method to the component without action helper as mentioned in the [guides of 3.18](https://guides.emberjs.com/v3.18.0/components/component-state-and-actions/#toc_combining-arguments-and-actions). So,

Controller.hbs:

```html
{{generic-err-modal 
  err=receivedErr   
  showDialog=this.showErrorModal 
  onSave=this.closePromptDialog
}}
```

Here, `this.closePromptDialog` will directly refer to the method in the backing class similar to any other class property like, `receivedErr`, in your case. The proper `this` binding will be taken care of by the `@action` decorator. The same is applicable for your actions inside `Component.hbs` file.

Comment: glad it helped :)

Comment: how would I access `closePromptDialog` from inside of a nested component a few levels down? Should I keep passing it as an arg to each child component?

Comment: Yes. You are correct, you have to pass it down to the inner component via the component tree explicitly